# Python 2 vs Python 3 straight bytes converting

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

I have Python 2 code, which works perfectly alright:

```
# python 2
key = 'L\x1e@\xael\xc0\xa9\xa3\x8d\x9e5\xac\x00\xe5\x98h'
# type(key) => <type 'str'>
```

**Originally my key is just some random 32bytes value. And here i share the only `repr()` values.**

So I can use some random bytes-like sequence as a string. 
But when it comes to Python3, my incoming string is in bytes:

```
# python 3
key = b'L\x1e@\xael\xc0\xa9\xa3\x8d\x9e5\xac\x00\xe5\x98h'
# type(key) => <class 'bytes'>
```

And I need to convert it to string "as it looks", without replacing any characters.

I tried to do it though ascii:

```
key_chuncks = [chr(s) for s in key]
# ['L', '\x1e', '@', '®', 'l', 'À', '©', '£', '\x8d', '\x9e', '5', '¬', '\x00', 'å', '\x98', 'h']
```

As you see `chr(s)` interpretes some bytes sequences as characters and I don't need this behavior.
Is there is a way, to convert my bytes to string "as it looks"? Without any character interpretation (decoding). ?

All I need is to convert `key_before` to `key_after` in Python3

```
key_before = b'L\x1e@\xael\xc0\xa9\xa3\x8d\x9e5\xac\x00\xe5\x98h'
key_after = 'L\x1e@\xael\xc0\xa9\xa3\x8d\x9e5\xac\x00\xe5\x98h'

# type(key_after) => <type 'str'>
```

Comment: Don't confuse the `repr()` output for multiple characters. What do you mean by 'as it looks'? That's the `repr()` output, which produces **debugging output**, a string literal notation meant to copy safely to a Python interpreter to re-create the vaule.

Comment: @martijn-pieters I agree, this values is just `repr()` view from interpretator. Originally my `key` is just some random 32 bytes, not symbols.

Comment: Then you have binary data. Why do you need this to be a string?

Comment: You can decode as Latin-1 (which maps bytes one-on-one to Unicode points). But the `repr()` output will then not use `\x` escapes; you'd have to use the `ascii()` function for that output.

Comment: @martijn-pieters because there is some other think involved, like MD5 of key, and base64encoding, to send it through http. I will try to use Latin-1, also reconsider my code.

Comment: Both MD5 hashing and base64 encoding require bytes as input.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, ops, i shamed. It looks like I should just cutout `b''` from straight `str(key)`. Like this: `str(key)[2:-1]` and it works. Thx for pointing me in right direction!

Comment: No, that doesn't work. You don't have the same value as your specified `key_after` now. You now have *literal* ``\`` and `x` characters followed by two hex characters. For your sample value you now have 49 characters, not  the original 16.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, meaning my question was pointless. And i just use the hint you give me about bytes :)

Comment: the key in your question is 16 bytes (`len(b'L\x1e@\xael\xc0\xa9\xa3\x8d\x9e5\xac\x00\xe5\x98h') == 16`). How do you get 32 bytes from it?

Comment: *"I have Python 2 code, which works perfectly alright"* show the result of Python 2 code (and the code itself if it is small). Remember `bytes = str` on Python 2 i.e., `b'\xca\xfe' == '\xca\xfe'` on Python 2. In other words `key == key_before` already. Why do you want to convert it to Unicode (`key_after`)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, looks like i don't. Sorry for bothering :) You can read comments above to know what was going on.  Also they key is 32 bytes in real, but represented by interpretator like this, so it looks like 16.

Comment: @yanik: *"they key is 32 bytes in real, but represented by interpretator like this, so it looks like 16"* -- **no** `len(key) == 16` *bytes*. Don't confuse `len(key)` and `len(repr(key))`. `key` is a sequence of bytes. Its size is `16` regardless of its `repr()`. It doesn't matter how it looks -- there are 16 bytes, no more, no less.